# how to Download file in react native from base64 string?

Tags: file, react-native, download, base64

I tried the following code to download the file.it works well. But i have a file in base64 format. So how can i download that?

```
const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir; // this is the pictures directory. You can check the available directories in the wiki.
let options = {
  fileCache: true,
  addAndroidDownloads: {
    useDownloadManager: true, // setting it to true will use the device's native download manager and will be shown in the notification bar.
    notification: true,
    path: PictureDir + '/Testing.pdf', // this is the path where your downloaded file will live in
    description: 'Downloading image.'
  }
};
config(options).fetch('GET', 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf').then((res) => {
  console.warn(res);
  alert('HIIII');
});
```

Comment: I used react-native-fetch-blob

Comment: @akshay how you used react-native-fetch-blob to download the base64 file. Can you explain to me?

Comment: i have followed the official [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob) of react-native-fetch-blob. You can do the same. The docs has clear explanation how to use.

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar If you have code snippet then please share..

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob this is ths link. if you scrooll down you can see a sample code of how to fetch a zip file and save it to local folder using this libary

Comment: Any examples on how to do this?

Comment: how to fix it? i have this problem. i have image base64 and i want to download and show in gallery folder ...it is my question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213519/i-want-to-show-my-image-in-gallery-folder-in-react-native