# show image in gallery folder in react native

Tags: react-native

i download image(base64 format) from rn-fetch-blob in DCIM folder in react native
but i want to show it in gallery, when i change its name it is not showing (manually in my phone)

my sample code is

```
    dwlImage(url){
    fileSize = parseInt((url).replace(/=/g,"").length * 0.75);
    const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    let progress = 0;
    this.setState({progress});
    let random=Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    var Base64Code = url.split("data:image/png;base64,"); //base64Image is my image base64 string
    var path = dirs.DCIMDir + '/akhavanApp/' +random+'.png';
    
    RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, Base64Code[0], 'base64')
        .then((res) => {
            Toast.show(strings.doneDownload);
            })
        .catch((err) => {
            Toast.show(strings.failedDownload);
            console.log("err "+JSON.stringify(err));
            })
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: hello samira, can you share your code? or explain in a better manner? you can also write in Fingilish (farsi written with latin alphabet)

Comment: can i have your id in telegram? i chat there?( i share my code in top of them... man mikham ax ro to gallery ya album bebinam, feghat to poshe DCIM mibinamesh)

Comment: @amirdorrrr here itis